# NodeJS - Parse CSV file

Tags: node.js, parsing, csv

I am trying to parse a CSV file using NodeJS.
so far I have tried these packages:

[Fast CSV](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv)

[YA-CSV](https://github.com/koles/ya-csv)

I would like to parse a CSV file into objects based on header.  I have been able to accomplish this with fast-csv but I have "'" values in my CSV file that I would like to ignore.  I cant seem to do this with fast-csv even though I try to use the

```
{escape:'"'}
```

I used ya-csv to try to get around this but no values are being written when I try:

```
var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader('YT5.csv', {columnsFromHeader:true, 'separator': ','});
var writer = new csv.CsvWriter(process.stdout);
reader.addListener('YT5', function(data){
writer.writeRecord(data);
});
```

I get no output, any help would be great.
Thanks.

Edit: 
I want the output in this format....

```
{ 'Video ID': '---kAT_ejrw',
'Content Type': 'UGC',
Policy: 'monetize',
'Video Title': 'Battlefield 3 Multiplayer - TDM na Kanałach Nouszahr (#3)',
'Video Duration (sec)': '1232',
Username: 'Indmusic',
Uploader: 'MrKacu13',
'Channel Display Name': 'MrKacu13',
'Channel ID': '9U6il2dwbKwE4SK3-qe35g',
'Claim Type': 'Audio',
'Claim Origin': 'Audio Match',
'Total Views': '11'
}
```

The header line is this.
Video ID,Content Type,Policy,Video Title,Video Duration (sec),Username,Uploader,Channel Display Name,Channel ID,Claim Type,Claim Origin,Total Views,Watch Page Views,Embedded Player Views,Channel Page Video Views,Live Views,Recorded Views,Ad-Enabled Views,Total Earnings,Gross YouTube-sold Revenue,Gross Partner-sold Revenue,Gross AdSense-sold Revenue,Estimated RPM,Net YouTube-sold Revenue,Net AdSense-sold Revenue,Multiple Claims?,Category,Asset ID,Channel,Custom ID,ISRC,GRid,UPC,Artist,Asset Title,Album,Label

All of these values will be filled in with some areas like title having single quotes.

This looks a mess so let me know if you need another format.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the .csv file you are trying to parse and the output you would like to have?

Comment: I just added an update, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved by using `ya-csv`

In order to use this I had to do a little more research but I did not know to add another listener for the data that I wanted to read and that it was just called 'data'

```
var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader('YT5.csv', {columnsFromHeader:true, 'separator': ','});
var writer = new csv.CsvWriter(process.stdout);
reader.addListener('data', function(data){
do something with data
}
reader.addListener('end', function(){
console.log('thats it');
}
```

This read the file without any issues from the single quotes.